# SQL Server 2008 Express Clear Recent Connection List

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I was trying to remove my recent connection list by deleting the mru.dat (in Application Data folder under windows xp) file as  pointed out in numerous tutorial over the internet(I just googled it) but was unable to find it. How am I supposed to clear it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/11/05/sql-server-clear-drop-down-list-of-recent-connection-from-sql-server-management-studio/):

> For SQL Server 2008:
>   `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\mru.dat`
>
> If you can not find mru.dat at above location look for `mru.dat` in following folder.
>   `C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ShellSEM\mru.dat`
>
> If you are using VISTA OS instead of XP OS. Replace `C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\Application Data\Microsoft\` with
>   `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\` and it should work.

Comment: I checked all the possible locations you mentioned but I'm unable to find the mru.dat file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using Tools -> Options -> Display X files in recently used list. Simply set it to 1 then back to 10. I had to fiddle with it and restart SSMS a few times. They might still be on the hard drive somewhere, but they don't show up in the MRU list.